# Is there easy way to install mytop on MAC OS 10.8 with mamp?

Tags: mysql, homebrew, osx-mountain-lion

Is there any easy way to install [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) on MAC OS 10.8. I tried with brew but its showing Error.

```
Unsatisfied dependency: DBD::mysql
Homebrew does not provide Perl dependencies; install with:
  cpan -i DBD::mysql
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the perl module DBD::mysql using CPAN.

http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED 2021**
For install and configure **Mytop** on your mac, follow this steps:

1. Install Mytop runnin this commands on terminal:

- First run:

```php
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

- Then run:

```php
brew install mytop
```

2. Create a mytop config file, the file must be in the folder of your mac user is: **/Users/your_user/**

```php
nano ~/.mytop
```

3. paste this and replace with yours credentials

```php
user=your_database_user
pass=your_database_password
host=localhost
db=your_database
delay=5
port=3306
socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
batchmode=0
header=1
color=1
idle=1
```

Finally save and run:

```php
mytop
```

---

### How to use it

```php
Help for mytop version 1.91   


  ? - display this screen
  # - toggle short/long numbers (not yet implemented)
  c - command summary view (based on Com_* counters)
  C - turn color on and off
  d - show only a specific database
  e - explain the query that a thread is running
  E - display current replication error
  f - show full query info for a given thread
  F - unfilter the display
  h - show only a specifc host's connections
  H - toggle the mytop header
  i - toggle the display of idle (sleeping) threads
  I - show innodb status
  k - kill a thread
  p - pause the display
  l - change long running queries hightlighing
  m - switch [mode] to qps (queries/sec) scrolling view
  o - reverse the sort order (toggle)
  q - quit
  r - reset the status counters (via FLUSH STATUS on your server)
  R - change reverse IP lookup
  s - change the delay between screen updates
  S - change slow query hightlighting
  t - switch to thread view (default)
  u - show only a specific user
  : - enter a command (not yet implemented)
  ! - Skip an error that has stopped replications (at your own risk)
```